# How can I make selection in inheritance case?

Tags: sql, database, inheritance

I have database table "Person", this person is a employee or admin. I have Person table, with information like ID, Password, and name. The person who will log in will be admin or employee, each has their own interface, but they will both inherit information from Person. So how can I represent this in database design, and how can I know if the selected person is admin or employee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a new column on the Person Table called UserType for example. This could be 1 for admin and 2 for employee.

You could have a totally seperate table called Users. This table could have a UserId, a PersonId and also a UserType.

Finally you could use ASP.NET authentication\authorisation. All user role management is built in. [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity)

Answer (score 0):

> " So how can I represent this in database design,"

Use a **subtype discriminator** - the attribute in the supertype entity that determines to which subtype the supertype occurrence is related.

Something like

```
                 Person                       |          Employee
 pers_name   pers_id   pers_pass  pers_type   |     pers_id    emp_attr
                                     E        |
                                     A        |
```

Where `pers_type` refers to an `Employee` or `Admin`